# argument of type 'function' is not iterable (python3 socket)

Tags: python-3.x, сокет

Новичок, начал изучать socket в питоне. Есть server.py

```
import socket
import time
import threading

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(10000000)

clients = []

def clients():
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)
        else:
            pass

t = threading.Thread(target=clients, name='Thread1')
t.start()

while True:
    data = input("Text: ")
    for client in clients:
        sock.sendto(data.encode(), client)
```

И client.py

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090 ))
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print(data.decode())
```

Сервер должен отправлять введенный текст всем клиентам.Но после того как хоть один клиент подключается, выбивает ошибку - argument of type 'function' is not iterable.

[image: До подключения]

[image: После]

Comment: Спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `clients` объявляется после списка `clients` и переопределяет это имя. Переименуйте или функцию или список.